# Error while communicating to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, perl

I want to use `jQuery` to display data into a table. The problem that I have is :"An error occurred while communicating to the server". I am using `Json` to encode data.

```
print $q->div({-id => 'id_div'});
 my $cScript = qq{ 
 \$(document).ready(function () {

        \$('#id_div').jtable({
            title: 'The person list',

            actions: {
                listAction: '/cgi-bin/list.pl',

            },
            fields: {
                ID: {
                    key: true,
                    list: false
                },
                Name: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '23%'
                },
               Surname: {
                     title: 'Surname',
                    width: '23%'
                },


            }

});
\$('#id_div').jtable('load');
});
};
print $q->script($cScript);
```

it is the first time i am trying to get data using Json and i cant figure out what may cause that problem. Please i need dome help . Thank you

Comment: look at server log file; and a side note, use `q{` instead of `qq{` so you don't have to backslash all `$` signs

Comment: [Thu Aug 01 11:29:44 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico

Comment: http://www.jtable.org/Home/Documents   this i the jQuery able i want

Comment: if you're new to ajax, you'll find `firebug extension` (http://getfirebug.com/) invaluable for tracing server calls